# Running Hive Query in Spark through Oozie 4.1.0.3

Tags: hadoop, spark-hive

Getting table not found exception while running Hive Query in Spark using Oozie version 4.1.0.3, as java action.

Copied hive-site.xml and hive-default.xml from hdfs path

workflow.xml used:

```
<start to="scala_java"/>
<action name="scala_java">
<java>
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<job-xml>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${appRoot}/env/devbox/hive-  site.xml</job-xml>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
<value>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${appRoot}/env/devbox/hive-default.xml</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>pool.name</name>
<value>${etlPoolName}</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
<value>${QUEUE_NAME}</value>
</property>
</configuration>
<main-class>org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit</main-class>
<arg>--master</arg>
<arg>yarn-cluster</arg>
<arg>--class</arg>
<arg>HiveFromSparkExample</arg>
<arg>--deploy-mode</arg>
<arg>cluster</arg>
<arg>--queue</arg>
<arg>testq</arg>
<arg>--num-executors</arg>
<arg>64</arg>
<arg>--executor-cores</arg>
<arg>5</arg>
<arg>--jars</arg>
<arg>datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,datanucleus-    rdbms-3.2.9.jar</arg>
<arg>TEST-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar</arg>
<file>TEST-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar</file>
</java>
```

INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: Table not found test_hive_spark_t1)

Exception in thread "Driver" org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.InvalidTableException: Table not found test_hive_spark_t1

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:980)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:950)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.lookupRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:79)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$OverrideCatalog$$super$lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:255)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:137)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:137)

    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$class.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$1.lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:255)
```

Comment: The "default" config files are just for **user information** - they are created at install time, from the hard-coded defaults in the JARs. It's the "site" config files that contain useful information, e.g. how to connect to the Metastore (default for that is *"just start an embedded Derby DB with no data inside"*... might explain the "table not found message!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Samson. I have the valid entry in hive-site.xml. The application is running fine via spark submit.  But through oozie, i am getting table not found exception.

Comment: @VenkidusamyK I am having the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

**A.** The *X-default* config files are just for user information; they are created at install time, from the hard-coded defaults in the JARs.

It's the ***X-site*** config files that contain useful information, e.g. how to connect to the Metastore (default for that is *"just start an embedded Derby DB with no data inside"*... might explain the "table not found message!

**B.** Hadoop components search for *X-site* config files **in the CLASSPATH**; and if they don't find them there, they silently fallback to *default*.

So you must tell Oozie to download them to local CWD via `<file>` instructions.
(Except for an explicit Hive Action that uses another, explicit, convention for its specific *hive-site* but that's not the case here)

Answer (score 0):

1. hive-default.xml is not needed.
2. Create a custom hive-site.xml and which has hive.metastore.uris property alone.
3. Pass the custom hive-site.xml in --files hive-site.xml as spark Arguments.
4. Remove the job-xml property and oozie-hive-defaults.